# Is there a way to generate ULIDs on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to insert some rows into a table using an SQL-script but the table key is an Ulid. Is there a way to generate Ulids in MySQL? It's not build-in as far as I know and Google does not come up with any community provides solutions either so I wonder if it's possible at all.

Comment: What is a Ulid?

Comment: Found it: https://github.com/ulid/spec

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the binary form of a ULID with this in MySQL:

```
CONCAT(UNHEX(CONV(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4))*1000), 10, 16)), RANDOM_BYTES(10))
```

And you can get the canonical string representation with theses functions defined at https://gist.github.com/kenji4569/47ce8bbd6bef7b85ba1f97e018f34cf3

Answer (score 2):

Composed:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ULID () RETURNS CHAR(26) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE s_hex CHAR(32);
    SET s_hex = LPAD(HEX(CONCAT(UNHEX(CONV(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4))*1000), 10, 16)), RANDOM_BYTES(10))), 32, '0');
    RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(s_hex, 1, 2), 16, 32), 2, '0'), LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(s_hex, 3, 15), 16, 32), 12, '0'), LPAD(CONV(SUBSTRING(s_hex, 18, 15), 16, 32), 12, '0')), 'V', 'Z'), 'U', 'Y'), 'T', 'X'), 'S', 'W'), 'R', 'V'), 'Q', 'T'), 'P', 'S'), 'O', 'R'), 'N', 'Q'), 'M', 'P'), 'L', 'N'), 'K', 'M'), 'J', 'K'), 'I', 'J');
END
```

```sql
select ULID();
```